# Meaning of symbol, 'curly N' in the equation of Linear Gaussian system dynamics

Tags: mobile-robot, control, robotic-arm, wheeled-robot, motion-planning

In the article of [Topological Based Representation](https://ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/mlr/papers/13-ivan-IJRR.pdf)(Page no. 12), the equation of the Linear Gaussian system dynamics is given as

[image]

In above equation what is the meaning of 'curly N'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are modeling the probability as a normal distribution with the given mean and variance.

Comment: So do u mean that mean = (At*xt-1 + at) and variance = Wt ? @SteveO

Comment: Yes, for $x_t$.